# Using CSS to replace nested tables in an old page

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I'm trying to update some old code to replace a bunch of nested tables in an old page. The page dynamically generates a list of "Environments" and for each environment the table contains a nested table that lists out each "Item" in that environment. I'm having some big time trouble rewriting this with CSS (I'm primarily a back end dev). The existing table needs each nested table to be collapsible so you start with only seeing the header for each nested table, and expand to see the body by clicking a little plus img. I know this needs to be done with multiple lists, which I can do with 1 table, but the nested tables are killing me. I would prefer to use jquery for the collapsing and sorting.

Here is some example html of what the table looks like. Keep in mind this is all dynamically generated and the nested tables need to be collapsible. The entire table should be sortable.

```
<table id='env' class='sortable-onload'>
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th class='sortable'>Environment</th>
      <th class='sortable'>Description</th>
      <th class='sortable'>Status</th>
      <th class='sortable'>Items</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Dynamic link to environment details</b></td>
        <td>Dynamic Description</td>
        <td>Dynamic Status</td>
        <td>
            <table> 
                <thead>
                <th>
                    <td>Individual Items</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                </th>
                </thead> //everything under this header should be collapsible 
                <tr>
                    <td id='item_id'>dynamic item name</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id='item_id'>dynamic item name</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id='item_id'>dynamic item name</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Dynamic link to environment details</b></td>
        <td>Dynamic Description</td>
        <td>Dynamic Status</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <th>
                    <td>Individual Items</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                </th>
                </thead> //everything under this header should be collapsible 
                <tr>
                    <td id='item_id'>dynamic item name</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id='item_id'>dynamic item name</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id='item_id'>dynamic item name</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This post includes a description of your broad goal rather than a specific question regarding an error or feature of your code. Will you update it to include a specific question that lends itself to a concise answer?

Comment: This looks like tabular data, nothing wrong with using a table.